# How to control the origin of the uiview under the uinavigationbar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I found that when I push a uitableviewcontroller from a uiviewcontroller, the origin of the pushed uitableview is right under the navigation bar. But if I replace the uitableview with another uiviewcontroller, the origin of the pushed uiview is from the 0. Therefore, there is some overlap between the navigation bar and the uiview. Anyone knows about this and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't visualize what your problem it, but i try to answer like this :). Any controller that push another view that view must have a container view. Example..
Navigation controller -> Root View -> Push view B -> Push view C..then any view B or C or Root View all of them inherit the navigation bar. All the controller view should not be overlapped by the navigation bar.